# how to call the server serving the page with a URL which references a python object function like "csvExport" and triggering it with a button

Tags: python, html, download, cherrypy

I have a python routine which I call with an HTML Button.  I cannot call from that button with AJAX.  It has to be a call via a URL, something like

```
onClick="location.href='server/csvExport'">
```

But how do I refer to the server which issued the running HTML, since that server may be one of many servers issuing this site?  Here is the Python side code which is an exposed method of the main object.  The server running is based on CherryPy.

```
def csvExport(self, **kwargs):

    sql = '''SELECT * FROM ...
    "...
    "...
    xLine += f2+f3+f1+f6+f8+f4+"\n"

    rtr = xLine
    CSV_Filename  = "ExportReport"

    cherrypy.response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/csv'
    cherrypy.response.headers['content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.csv'% CSV_Filename

    return rtr

csvExport.exposed = True
```

TIA

DK

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `window.location.host` DOM indirection to get the server reference and it has to be preceded by `'HTTP://'` The two will produce a URL like `HTTP://soandso.com:8050` with a port number to identify the running site.  That site can now be supplemented with an object function like `csvExport` to get a final and full URL reference to the call you are trying to make. e.g. `'HTTP://soandso.com:8050/csvExport'` and that is sufficient to refer to any server running this site.

Here is a practical way of planting this event into a button with jQuery:

```
        dLoadCall = window.location.host+"/csvExport";
        dLoadCall2 = "window.open('http://"+dLoadCall+"')";
        $("#dload").attr("onClick",dLoadCall2);
```

The HTML button might look like this before the event insertion:

```
<input id="dload" type="button" value="Export CSV"/>
```

And this is how it would look afterward:

```
<input id="dload" type="button" value="Export CSV" onclick="window.open('http://192.168.19.249:8140/csvExport')">`
```

Now you can click on the button and call the Python method `csvExport:` on the server serving this site.

DK